# filtrar en django mediante una expresión

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo un modelo con un campo "fecha" y necesito hacer un filtro de esa fecha restandole 30 días, es decir:

```
fecha-timedelta(days=30)<=data.today()
```

Se trata de filtrar por una expresión en SQL sería algo como:

```
select * from mitable where fecha-30<=now()
```

¿cómo se realiza este filtro en django?

```
mimodelo = Mimodelo.objects.filter(?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible forma de hacerlo.

En lugar de restar 30 días a `fecha` (el campo de la base de datos) es más práctico operar sobre la fecha fija que conocemos `data.today()`. Para calcular la diferencia de fechas usamos un [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
from datetime import timedelta
highest_day = data.today() + timedelta(days=30)
```

En caso de que en lugar de usar `data.today()` quisieras hacerlo sobre "hoy", la fecha actual podría obtener `datetime.datetime.now()` pero puede ser interesante utilizar [django.utils.timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) dependiendo de tu caso de uso concreto (generalmente si querrás usarlo)

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now()
highest_day = now + timedelta(days=30)
```

Luego pedimos todos las filas cuyo campo `fecha` sea anterior (más antiguo) que la máxima fecha deseada (`highest_day`). Para hacer hacer el `field lookup` usamos [lte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#lte). Si quisieramos comprobar que sea posterior más actual usaríamos [gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte).

```
mimodelo = Mimodelo.objects.filter(fecha__lte=highest_day)
```

El código completo sería:

```
from datetime import timedelta
highest_day = data.today() + timedelta(days=30)
mimodelo = Mimodelo.objects.filter(fecha__lte=highest_day)
```

Comment: veo que filtras fecha>=timezone.now()-timetodelta(days=30)

Comment: Igual entendí mal la pregunta. Creo que ahora es correcto.